# How to install Samsung 2026 printer driver on Ubuntu 15

Tags: drivers, printing, samsung

I have been using Ubuntu for the last few years but do not know much about using commands on the terminal.
I have just bought a Samsung 2026 laser printer. But, despite all my efforts have failed to install the driver!!

I have followed the instructions on this website for samsung 2020 printer, but, failed!

I have downloaded the driver folder (although everybody syas it should be called 'uld' the one download is named as 'upd'). But, then on, whatever i tried i failed.

Is there a kind sould who can tell me how to install this driver? I need an absolute idiot's guide to install.